# Finding Max Weekly Average on a month

Tags: max, average

I am stuck on my query attempt.  I have a table that lists test results with their dates.  I need to run a query to return the highest weekly average for a particular month.

I have the first part figured out:

SELECT `Effluent BOD5`, WEEK(Date)
FROM bod
WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2020 AND MONTH (Date) = 4
ORDER BY WEEK(Date)

Returns:

Effluent BOD5  /   WEEK(Date)

10                14

14                14

9                 15

6                 16

7                 16

11                17

8                 17

I need to get the result of 12 (which is the highest weekly average (week 14).

Any help would be great![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with this and figured it out!  Here is what I used:

SELECT max(Total)
FROM
(SELECT week, avg(test) AS Total
From
(SELECT `Effluent BOD5` test, WEEK(Date) week
FROM bod
WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2020 AND MONTH(Date) = 4
ORDER BY WEEK(Date),`Effluent BOD5` desc)ab
GROUP BY week)ac